# Xamarin.Forms Previewer error sqlite

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Need help.

In my project, I'm using SQLite. Visual 2017 with lastest Update

When I try to view the XML with, the following error occurs:

> System.DLLNotFoundException was ..   /system/lib64/libsqlite.so

error print

[image: error print]

Comment: I'm having the same dll missing problem, and things work on device. My guess is this dll is missing in Android 7 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had that Exception before but it was unrelated to the XML previewer. Something I had to do was add a reference to the assembly System.Data.SQLite in my platform project. Once you do that, you should see Mono.Data.Sqlite under your platform project's References. This should fix the DLLNotFoundException you are experiencing. As for the previewer, I never got that to work.

Comment: Thanks for answering me.

I added the reference as you explained it to me.

But the error was not resolved.

Comment: Ah sorry. I didn't see your image before. I wish you the best of luck figuring that out. I just never use the previewer since it often caused me problems.